# SharePoint 2010 move bcs profile page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, profile, bcs

Is it possible to move the SharePoint 2010 BCS profile page, normally located under:

```
https://***.orbitone.com:443/__bdc/https___***_orbitone_com/Projects_1.aspx?JOB_ID={0}
```

To:

```
https://***.orbitone.com:443/Projects_1.aspx?JOB_ID={0}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a work around I guess but works well. I have tried it out.

1.) Create the profile page in the desired location (Web Part page)

2.) Export the web parts(2 web parts) from original profile page and add it to you custom page.

3.) Connect the web parts and test the page whether it is working properly like the OOTB profile page.

4.) Create a new action in the External Content Type and give the above new URL in the below format

**https://???.orbitone.com:443/Projects_1.aspx?JOB_ID={0}**

5.) Select the other parameters appropriately. Don't forget to **give parameter as the identifier(JOB ID)**. Make sure you select this action as **default action**.

That's it :)

It should work in the way you expect. Let me know if you face any issues.